# advanced search with limited time range

Tags: data-tables, advancedsearch

im designing a data table page from a CRM system with complicated advanced search（up to 10 fields?）.

The table display information from a very large amount of data, to avoid losing any of them, users can only pick data from a limited time range(30 days).

THE scenario is, we also allow user to search data with an unique ID(exact match).and when they do so, any other search settings including time limit are unnecessary.So now our solution is invalidate other search settings in backstage when user type something in ID field and hit search. But im pretty sure this solution violate several usability rules.

How can i do?

Comment: Are you doing that to avoid losing users? Or to avoid losing data? Either way, seems odd...What you should do is: try to implement the most sensible implementation you can. Then test that on real Users (User Testing and/or AB Testing, in conjunction with analytics). Then maybe come back to this site and ask a question that shows you tried something and highlights where Users indicate problems, then your question will meet this system's guidelines and you will probably get an Answer that is specific enough to make use of.